# How to fetch the login person name through robobrowser module

Tags: python-3.x, robobrowser

I tried to fetch the login name after submitting the form but output is printing as "nothing". I believe mistake in html tag between start and end but not sure what is the wrong. Please help on below.

```
import config
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
br = RoboBrowser()
br.open('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login')
form = br.get_form(id="login-form")
form['Email address']=config.username
form['Password']=config.password
br.submit_form(form)
src = str(br.parsed())
start='<div class="name">'      
end='</div>'
try:
    result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), src).group(l)
    print (result)
except:
    pint ('nothing')
```

**output**

```
nothing
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be form['username'] and form['password'] ?

Comment: @Isma: No. Which I mentioned is able to login..

Comment: The fields are named username and password not Email address and Password

Comment: @Isma. No. If you put like this form['username']=config.username. below error will display

werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.